# Have ColdFusion 8 process .cfm pages outside of wwwroot?

Tags: coldfusion

With Visual Studio/.Net I'm able to create a working folder outside of the standard wwwroot folder. I'd like to do similar with ColdFusion, by not using the "C:\ColdFusion8\wwwroot\" location. Is it possible to have CF process files in, say "C:\cf\dev" using a virtual folder? I thought this was possible with CF Mappings, but that appears to only work with includes, cfc's, etc.

I'm on Win 7 with IIS, but using the built-in CF web server (Developer version), default port 8500.

Comment: *"Is it possible to have CF process files in, say "C:\cf\dev" using a virtual folder?"* - Certainly. Have you tried?

Comment: It's amazing what simply trying would accomplish eh?

Answer (score 5):

It's unclear what you are asking. Are you asking:

1. Is it possible to have my *web server* serve file from outside the web root?
2. Is it possible to have *ColdFusion* process files outside the ColdFusion root?

Those are two distinct questions.

The answer to both is "yes" though.

For a file to be web browsable, the web site needs to know where the files are, and they need to expose this location with a virtual directory. So /myWebBrowsablVirtualDir => /myDirNotInWebroot. That's fine.

And if you browse to /myWebBrowsablVirtualDir/myFile.cfm, the web server will pass the request to ColdFusion for processing.

For *ColdFusion* to find files (say myFile.cfm includes /someOtherDirOutsideTheColdFusionRoot/anotherFile.cfm, then you - similarly - need to let ColdFusion know where the file is, by creating a ColdFusion mapping for it.